# loopback + remote calls + debug

Tags: debugging, console, loopbackjs

if there is a server error, my XHR will return a 500 error code along with a vague description.

what is the best practice on viewing error logs, debug output, etc?

can this output be sent to my console?

Answer (score 1):

what will work for me now is using the debug object.

`var debug = require('debug')('my:debug:string');`

then specifying the debug string when launching the app.

`DEBUG=my:debug:string node .`